# Intuition behind tail recursionin Fibonacci

Tags: python, recursion

The following code compute the nth Fibonnacci number:

```py
def fib(n, a=0, b=1):
    return fib(n-1, b, a+b) if n > 0 else a
```

I am struggling to understand how to come up with such a solution.
It looks like the formula comes from a void. However, there must be some steps that led so such a formula. Unfortunately, such a scaffolding has been removed and a clean formula is given.

PS: I am aware that Python does not have TCO.

If there is some graph or animation, it would be perfect.

Comment: Hint: how would you write a generator of all of the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: I will compute  them in an increasing way. We know that f(1) = 1 and f(0) = 0. Now I compute f(2) = f(1) + f(0) and store it. Same for f(3) = f(2) + f(1), f(2) and f(1) are both stored at this point, I do the sum and store the result. What troubles me here, is that we are somehow going backward with the recursion.

Comment: You're not going backwards.  The COUNTER is going backwards, but the numbers are increasing.  When the counter reaches 0, you've reached the "desired" entry in the list.

Comment: @TimRoberts Is there a way to do it with the counter going upwards ?

Comment: Why would you care?  The counter is an implementation detail.  It's tracking "how many numbers do I have to go?"  You need that because this function is SPECIFICALLY generating the Nth number, and not attempting to generate the whole sequence.

Answer (score 1):

So.  The best explanation I can come up with.  Normally, Fibonacci numbers start with 0, 1, to give the sequence

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...
```

But you can have sequences that start with any pair of numbers.  For example

```
2, 5, 7, 12, 19, 31, 50, ....
```

Now here's an interesting fact.  Look at the sequence

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ...
```

it's one of these alternative sequences, but it starts with 1, 1.  And it just happens to be the elements of the Fibonacci sequence missing the first one.
And

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, ...
```

is another of these alternate sequences, but it's also the Fibonacci sequence missing the first two elements.

So `fib(n, a, b)` is just "give me the nth element of the 'alternative' Fibonacci sequence whose first two elements are `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

n is the reversed index of fib values

a is fib(n)  beginning at 0

b is fib(n+1)

Answer (score 0):

As n decreases with every recursive call, `b` is passed as the new `a` while the new `b` is the old `a+b`. Notice how that represents exactly the fibonacci logic:

```
n  0 1 1 2 3 5 8 
5  a b
4    a b
3      a b
2        a b
1          a b
0            a b  # -> fib(5) == 5 (== a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be just a fancy way of rewriting a simple loop.

Note that `n` in the recursive code does not interact at all with `a` or `b`. It serves just as a counter. It decreases by 1 each time, and when it becomes 0, recursion ends. So it really is just a `for` loop with `n` iterations. Then the way `a` and `b` are switched everytime, which is fairly a standard way of calculating Fibonacci.

So the following is more or less equivalent rewriting of the code:

```py
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

Answer (score 0):

Trace through the calls, for n=5 in this case:

```
def fib(n, a=0, b=1):
    return fib(n-1, b, a+b) if n > 0 else a

call fib(5)
    call fib(4, 1, 1)
        call fib(3, 1, 2)
            call fib(2, 2, 3)
                call fib(1, 3, 5)
                    call fib(0, 5, 8)
                        return 5
                    return 5
                return 5
            return 5
        return 5
    return 5
```

Comment: Your comment about the counter going backward made a lot of sens. Thanks ! Is there a way to have an upward counter? I guess no, but can't explain why clearly.

Comment: I mean, having an upward counter but without using loops.

Comment: To use an upward counter, you'd need to pass 4 things: the counter, the target n, and a and b.  It's added overhead for no purpose.  Remember you would NOT use this solution for generating arbitrary lengthy sections of the sequence.  Every recursive call adds overhead.

Comment: Ok, I get it. However, the time and space complexity of both the upward and backward counters are equal. Am I right?

Comment: No; to use an upward counter with the recursive solution, you have to pass an additional parameter.  That is additional space at every call.  Not much, of course, but they are not identical.

Comment: But somehow, the "not much" is a constant part of my big-O? So, what I meant is, in practice they are not the same, but in theory they are.

Comment: Constants are dropped in big-O notation.   If two algorithms processing N items take N and 4N time, they are both O(N).  If you triple the number of items, the time goes up by a factor of 3.  That's what big-O tells you.  It doesn't tell you the absolute time.

Comment: Agree! Thanks a lot. A final remark, you still have that triangular shape in the trace because Python does not support Tail Call Optimisation, right?

Comment: Well, I would have described it that way even if it did have tail recursion, because it makes the concept clearer..  Again, that really shouldn't be relevant to your programming decisions.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean by "that really shouldn't be relevant to your programming decisions"...

Answer (score 0):

this is basically the iterative version but written in recursive form:

```
def fibi(n,a=0,b=1):
    while n>0:
        a,b = b, a+b
        n = n-1
    return a
```

in both cases n is no more that a counter that tell us how many times we should do the `a,b = b, a+b` step, is the same if we initialize a counter `i=0` and count up to until we get to `n` or like here we decrease `n` which in this case tell us how many step we have left